# How to get the single record by id when using Include()

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to create a linq database call to retrieve a bunch of information. The user can have a list of ApplicationForms and ApplicationLogic

From the View im passing the route values for the MemberID and the ApplicationID.

From the linq i want to get the single ApplicationForm and the single ApplicationLogic based on the ApplicationID that is passed.

```
   public async Task<Members> GetApplicationDetails(int MemberID, int ApplicationID)
    {
        var GetApplication = await _dbContext.Members
                                    .Include(x => x.Members_PersonalInformation)
                                    .Include(x => x.Members_BankRefundDetails)
                                    .Include(x => x.Members_ResidentialAddress)
                                    .Include(x => x.ApplicationForms)  //I want to get the application by ApplicationID
                                    .Include(x => x.ApplicationLogic)  //I want to get the logic by ApplicationID
                                    .Where(x => x.ID == MemberID)
                                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        return GetApplication;
    }
```

My Members Model

```
  public virtual ICollection<ApplicationForms> ApplicationForms { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationLogic> ApplicationLogic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Members_PersonalInformation> Members_PersonalInformation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Members_BankRefundDetails> Members_BankRefundDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Members_ResidentialAddress> Members_ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is currently happening?  How are your relationships defined?

Comment: Yes they are, all relationships are defined, I've used Include() in other areas where it requires to return a list. But currently as its the Application Details page. I want the single row by the ApplicationID for the ApplicationForms and ApplicationLogic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After modifying the properties types as to which @ShaneRay

```
 public async Task<Members> GetApplicationDetails(int MemberID, int ApplicationID)
    {
        var GetApplication = await _dbContext.Members
                                   .Include(x => x.Members_PersonalInformation)
                                   .Include(x => x.Members_BankRefundDetails)
                                   .Include(x => x.Members_ResidentialAddress)
                                   .Include(x => x.ApplicationFormsSingle).Where(x => x.ApplicationFormsSingle.ID == ApplicationID)
                                   .Include(x => x.ApplicationLogicSingle).Where(x => x.ApplicationLogicSingle.ApplicationFormsID == ApplicationID)
                                   .SingleOrDefaultAsync(f => f.ID == MemberID);

        return GetApplication;
    }
```

Comment: If my solution worked for you, then you should mark my answer as correct rather than posting your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your member properties types to be T rather than ICollection.

```
public virtual ApplicationForms ApplicationForms { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationLogic ApplicationLogic { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection< Members_PersonalInformation> Members_PersonalInformation { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Members_BankRefundDetails> Members_BankRefundDetails { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Members_ResidentialAddress> Members_ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
```